# Change color of a specific coordinate

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the color of a certain coordinate, actually is the same coordinate which has the annotation.

Any ideas?

```
p1 <- ggplot(HiBAP1517, aes(BPM, Yld)) + 
  geom_point(shape=16) + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm, se = F) + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold"))
p2 <- p1 + 
  annotate(geom="text", x=1879, y=892.02, label="Rialto",
           color="darkorange", size = 5, hjust=1, vjust=1.3, fontface =2)
p3 <- p2 + 
  annotate(geom="text", x=1654.75, y=834.2375, label="Savannah",
           color="firebrick1", size = 5, hjust=1, vjust=1, fontface =2)
pfinal <- p3 + 
  labs(x = expression("AGDM"[PM]^{}*(gm^{-2})),
       y = expression("GY"*(gm^{-2})))
```

This is my output, but I would like to change the color (instead of black) of those 2 coordinates:

[image: output]

Data sample:

```
Genotype,BPM,Yld
1,1767.793447,747.0708034
2,2074.815941,775.8880562
3,2197.933995,854.3810136
5,2085.627286,845.9306447
6,1908.97774,841.4318038
7,2120.24666,875.5534429
8,2226.617509,764.3849451
9,2035.68002,810.2658242
10,2153.727,861.7024631
11,1993.568134,782.5763292
12,2013.199982,822.6565187
13,2078.275912,837.2819632
14,2042.456487,802.6913977
16,1840.058841,767.6509829
17,2013.338146,801.2064103
18,2087.151352,822.1910199
19,1988.038384,859.573342
20,2083.092896,887.2783898
21,2072.905795,861.3044422
23,1849.744525,723.5014595
24,1785.04038,747.4940519
25,2078.402869,835.7669124
26,1698.390774,681.256732
27,2065.842661,852.3073467
28,2020.285009,811.6889063
29,2039.137248,821.7951099
30,1855.665106,781.0350726
31,1792.32475,744.9001931
32,1992.616447,860.7054072
33,2025.79755,834.1452611
34,2023.274784,835.4102703
35,1703.837196,682.9995098
36,1740.44177,713.3121368
37,1970.331012,816.5239645
38,1990.223669,838.9949534
39,2081.559891,822.5936391
40,1968.990856,852.1259441
41,2178.322511,920.80226
42,1887.572381,721.0746569
43,2103.964882,821.6521912
44,2097.040605,873.0062511
45,1864.779016,755.1746154
46,1935.743565,895.4951282
47,2191.797365,888.7284615
48,1968.150754,863.7490909
49,1858.735915,759.7144347
50,1933.34954,774.4202087
51,1680.540128,717.2402198
52,1748.214736,783.3395385
53,2183.694734,855.5897436
54,2142.662802,912.635349
55,1892.205584,776.5070164
56,2230.304238,887.8378102
57,2141.882287,903.7212821
58,1983.755009,815.5541958
59,1954.653032,743.0290819
60,1801.192428,718.5391635
61,1920.709571,808.6727692
62,1796.291216,699.0526007
63,2026.074655,909.3961954
64,1863.574774,729.9547929
65,1924.971832,770.2818388
66,2129.910527,794.0297343
67,2090.201938,809.6094569
68,1987.074651,731.8146606
69,2053.104282,839.4181954
70,1872.403668,787.2339391
71,1961.144455,824.335206
72,2135.414422,881.9237509
73,1857.780642,779.9428159
74,2058.696424,840.2234927
76,2169.489819,805.3868184
77,1891.844601,756.8752683
78,2099.708756,830.6765073
79,1976.981377,786.4878009
81,1932.909878,800.0033701
82,2101.603045,834.2990498
83,1867.872044,735.4201911
84,1870.947954,703.6186056
85,2135.962836,798.3315211
86,1859.497846,762.135947
87,1966.35974,776.6730353
88,2088.086246,808.0767316
89,1964.134743,851.5441764
90,2211.81001,866.3412008
91,1881.56405,805.7430148
92,1921.941058,725.2508829
93,1576.551861,606.5037422
95,2249.995426,882.4130493
96,2092.694714,778.8794369
97,2099.861152,840.9202391
98,1837.6733,760.0247786
99,1986.16533,796.1227279
100,1981.047087,747.7190033
Rialto,1879,892.02
Savannah,1654.75,834.2375
```

Comment: Can you please add a reproducible example? Paste here your data or part of it or a toy dataset, and show us your expected output (you can use paint to show us).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to change the color of the ***points*** corresponding to the labels, since their precise coordinates along the x/y-axis aren't shown, and you'll have more work pinpointing them before the question about color comes up. If that's not the case, I'll delete my answer.

[image: result]

```
# define color corresponding to each genotype
HiBAP1517$color <- case_when(HiBAP1517$Genotype == "Savannah" ~ "firebrick1",
                             HiBAP1517$Genotype == "Rialto" ~ "darkorange",
                             TRUE ~ "black")

# plot
ggplot(HiBAP1517,
       # specify color aesthetic here for both geom_point & geom_text to inherit
       aes(x = BPM, y = Yld, color = color)) + 

  geom_point(shape = 16) +
  geom_smooth(color = "#3366FF", # maintain default color for geom_smooth line
              method = lm, se = F) +

  # position labels based on their coordinates, rather than hard-code them via annotate()
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(Genotype %in% c("Savannah", "Rialto"), 
                               Genotype, "")),
            hjust = 1, vjust = 1) +

  # use defined colors directly
  scale_color_identity() + 

  # other aesthetic parameters, irrelevant to the question at hand
  labs(x = expression("AGDM"[PM]^{}*(gm^{-2})),
       y = expression("GY"*(gm^{-2}))) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color="black", size=14, face="bold"))
```

Data used:

```
> dput(HiBAP1517)
structure(list(Genotype = c("1", "2", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", 
"9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", 
"33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", 
"44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", 
"55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", 
"66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "76", "77", 
"78", "79", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", 
"90", "91", "92", "93", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"Rialto", "Savannah"), BPM = c(1767.793447, 2074.815941, 2197.933995, 
2085.627286, 1908.97774, 2120.24666, 2226.617509, 2035.68002, 
2153.727, 1993.568134, 2013.199982, 2078.275912, 2042.456487, 
1840.058841, 2013.338146, 2087.151352, 1988.038384, 2083.092896, 
2072.905795, 1849.744525, 1785.04038, 2078.402869, 1698.390774, 
2065.842661, 2020.285009, 2039.137248, 1855.665106, 1792.32475, 
1992.616447, 2025.79755, 2023.274784, 1703.837196, 1740.44177, 
1970.331012, 1990.223669, 2081.559891, 1968.990856, 2178.322511, 
1887.572381, 2103.964882, 2097.040605, 1864.779016, 1935.743565, 
2191.797365, 1968.150754, 1858.735915, 1933.34954, 1680.540128, 
1748.214736, 2183.694734, 2142.662802, 1892.205584, 2230.304238, 
2141.882287, 1983.755009, 1954.653032, 1801.192428, 1920.709571, 
1796.291216, 2026.074655, 1863.574774, 1924.971832, 2129.910527, 
2090.201938, 1987.074651, 2053.104282, 1872.403668, 1961.144455, 
2135.414422, 1857.780642, 2058.696424, 2169.489819, 1891.844601, 
2099.708756, 1976.981377, 1932.909878, 2101.603045, 1867.872044, 
1870.947954, 2135.962836, 1859.497846, 1966.35974, 2088.086246, 
1964.134743, 2211.81001, 1881.56405, 1921.941058, 1576.551861, 
2249.995426, 2092.694714, 2099.861152, 1837.6733, 1986.16533, 
1981.047087, 1879, 1654.75), Yld = c(747.0708034, 775.8880562, 
854.3810136, 845.9306447, 841.4318038, 875.5534429, 764.3849451, 
810.2658242, 861.7024631, 782.5763292, 822.6565187, 837.2819632, 
802.6913977, 767.6509829, 801.2064103, 822.1910199, 859.573342, 
887.2783898, 861.3044422, 723.5014595, 747.4940519, 835.7669124, 
681.256732, 852.3073467, 811.6889063, 821.7951099, 781.0350726, 
744.9001931, 860.7054072, 834.1452611, 835.4102703, 682.9995098, 
713.3121368, 816.5239645, 838.9949534, 822.5936391, 852.1259441, 
920.80226, 721.0746569, 821.6521912, 873.0062511, 755.1746154, 
895.4951282, 888.7284615, 863.7490909, 759.7144347, 774.4202087, 
717.2402198, 783.3395385, 855.5897436, 912.635349, 776.5070164, 
887.8378102, 903.7212821, 815.5541958, 743.0290819, 718.5391635, 
808.6727692, 699.0526007, 909.3961954, 729.9547929, 770.2818388, 
794.0297343, 809.6094569, 731.8146606, 839.4181954, 787.2339391, 
824.335206, 881.9237509, 779.9428159, 840.2234927, 805.3868184, 
756.8752683, 830.6765073, 786.4878009, 800.0033701, 834.2990498, 
735.4201911, 703.6186056, 798.3315211, 762.135947, 776.6730353, 
808.0767316, 851.5441764, 866.3412008, 805.7430148, 725.2508829, 
606.5037422, 882.4130493, 778.8794369, 840.9202391, 760.0247786, 
796.1227279, 747.7190033, 892.02, 834.2375)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-96L))
```